For 'a%' why is one of the results that could be returned 'z6ra'?

For 'a%' why is one of the results that could be returned 'z6ra'?

Please don't post pictures of text. Markdown provides formatting for tables

You have misread the patterns in the text you quote.  You read a% where it says %a.
The pattern %a matches any string that ends with a.  The string Z6ra ends with a, so the pattern would match it.
The pattern a% matches any string that begins with a.  The string Z6ra does not begin with a, so the pattern would not match it.
